# Function to flatten nested iterables but not some excepted types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this function to flatten nested iterables (with arbitrary depth) but refrain from flattening excepted types (for instance, `string` or `tuple`):

```
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, Type


def flatten(item: Iterable, except_types: Type | Tuple[Type] | None = None):
    if except_types is not None and isinstance(item, except_types):
        yield item
    for element in item:
        if except_types is not None and isinstance(element, except_types):
            yield element
            continue
        try:
            yield from flatten(element, except_types)
        except TypeError:
            yield element
```

Therefore it works this way:

```
>>> list(flatten([(1, 2), [(3, 4), [(5, 6), (7, 8)]]], tuple))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Could this code be made more concise and elegant, and yet easily readable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The function fails with strings**. If the input includes a `str`, the
function hits a `RecursionError`. Strings are often a hassle with functions
like this because even after you flatten a string once (eg, converting `"foo"`
into a list of characters) the elements in the list are of the same iterable
type that you started with, `str`. The bottom line is that this kind of
function will need some special logic to terminate when it hits single
characters.

**Logic can be simplified if `except_types` defaults to an empty tuple**. It
makes the `isinstance()` check easier.

**When writing a recursive function, resist the temptation to look ahead**. You
check types twice, at the start of the function and right before recursing.
That's a common temptation (I saw it dozens of times in coding interviews, for
example) and it almost always leads one down a more difficult path. Much better
is to recurse confidently/blindly and let the function's termination checks at
the start of the function do their job.

```
def flatten(xs, except_types = ()):
    # Terminate for except_types.
    if isinstance(xs, except_types):
        yield xs
        return

    # Terminate for single characters.
    if isinstance(xs, str) and len(xs) == 1:
        yield xs
        return

    # Terminate for non-iterable.
    try:
        it = iter(xs)
    except TypeError:
        yield xs
        return

    # Iterate and recurse with confidence.
    for x in it:
        yield from flatten(x, except_types)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. A silly doubt: why in many examples I saw online, the parameter to be flattened is called `xs`?

Comment: @VBobCat It's based on a common naming convention for situations where you don't know anything specific about the object you have. In math, for example, an unknown is often called `x`. If you have a collection of unknowns, you pluralize it by adding an "s" to get `xs`. I like the convention because it tightly links each single element `x` to its parent collection `xs`. By contrast, if we use your original name, `item`, for the collection, we don't have a good name to use for elements (you used `element`, which is OK, but it lacks the tight linkage that `xs` and `x` have with each other).

Comment: @FMc It seems to be better to use `item`/`items` or `element`/`elements` (for loop variable and function parameter respectively). `Xs` imply mathematical context (such as a list of co-ordinates), but here we operate on a higher, OOP level.